# Displaying session, post, etc. data with Kohana 3 profiler?

Tags: php, kohana

I'm getting started with Kohana and haven't found a way to display session, cookie, post and server variables on a page with the profiler. When there's an exception, the default error view shows you what's wrong and exposes this environment data by default at the bottom.

Is there anyway to get the profiler to share the same info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The profiler does not show global data on in Kohana v3. You would have to create a different view (or copy `system/views/profiler/stats.php` and edit) to show this additional information.

By default, this information is not shown on the profiler because it can be a security risk if the session contains private data, or `$_POST` contains a password, etc.

Comment: Augmenting the stats view was the solution. I extracted the desired environmental data from the exception view and added it to the profiler's stats view. Some css tweeking, and now my profiler shows everything going on. I have my app configured to only show the profiler when the viewed from the right subdomain, which also is independently password protected. Thanks for the post.